# Teamcity API is it possible to get build details as part of changes call

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible to get build details from Changes api call.

I am trying following but it doesn't return anything for build field.

`http://server/app/rest/changes?locator=build:(id:13046)&fields=build,change`

I am getting a list of changes but no build details, is it possible to achieve this with single api call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking the Change API, you can use the `builds` API with something like this:

```
http://server/app/rest/builds?locator=buildId:13046&fields=build(id,buildTypeId,number,status,state,running,percentageComplete,branchName,defaultBranch,unspecifiedBranch,history,pinned,statusText,changes(count,href,change))
```

You can find the full API specification for available properties here:

```
http://server/app/rest/swagger.json
```

Inside the the `Build` definition.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful.